# Publishing Outlook addin from the command line (part of automated build in TeamCity)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have an Outlook Addin developed in Visual Studio targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2. From inside VS I can publish the application to a folder of my choice, and the installer/uninstaller works as expected.

I want to be able to do this from command line, and pass the version number to be used.

The goal is to a 'publish' step as part of TeamCity build process.

Is it possible to publish the addin using the 'dotnet publish' command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you can not use the .Net Core 'dotnet publish' command, I ad to use msbuild command.

To build & publish the Outlook Addin with a specific version the following command line works:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:publish
                       /p:PublishDir="publish" 
                       /p:Configuration=Release
                       /p:Platform="Any CPU" 
                       /p:ApplicationVersion=X.X.X.X
```

This requires the 'Publish' UI to be configured in Visual Sudio.